# Redirecting to payment gateway url

Tags: magento, magento2

Hello i am busy creating a payment gateway for magneto I have got an observer that uses the sales_model_service_quote_submit_success event.I get the response from the curl but I don't know what to do to redirect to this URL. It can be a redirect or just opening a new tab and following the url

I have tried to use header('Location: '.$newURL) but i guess I can't because this is Magento. How would I do this? I just want to redirect to the URL and capture the response if payment was successful

Answer (score 0):

With redirection, you authorize a customer's payment by sending your customer to an Amazon Payment Services gateway page for payment. To process a payment, your site displays a checkout page where your customer agrees to a total amount to pay.

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: How would i send the user to that url?